# change name of use associated object in current namespace

Tags: namespaces, fortran

I feel like this has to be a duplicate, but I can't seem to find it anywhere and I didn't get anything with a very quick google search.

Is there a way to change the name of stuff in a module so that it doesn't conflict with the name of something local (or global)?  Consider the example:

```
module namespace
   real x  !some data
   contains
   subroutine foo()
     write(0,*) "foo!"
   end subroutine foo
end module
subroutine foo()
   write(0,*) "foo is the new bar :)"
end subroutine

program main
  use namespace
  real x
  call foo() !should print "foo is the new bar"
  call namespacefoo() !somehow call module namespace's version of foo
end program main
```

The above code doesn't compile because `x` isn't defined.  Of course if I don't want a local variable named `x`, then I could `use namespace, only: foo`, but it seems a little cumbersome to have to mangle my local variable names.  (as a side note, I'm pretty sure that I've seen this before with some magic in the `only` part of the statement ...)

---

For the benefit of those who also know python, I'm looking for something similar to python's:

```
import namespace as other_namespace
```

Or I guess since Fortran doesn't quite have that level of namespace control:

```
from namespace import somefunc as otherfunc
from namespace import somedata as otherdata
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need renaming:

```
[luser@cromer stackoverflow]$ cat ren.f90
module namespace
   real x  !some data
   contains
   subroutine foo()
     write(0,*) "foo!"
   end subroutine foo
end module
subroutine foo()
   write(0,*) "foo is the new bar :)"
end subroutine

program main
  use namespace, local_name => x, namespacefoo => foo  
  real x
  call foo() !should print "foo is the new bar"
  call namespacefoo() !somehow call module namespace's version of foo
end program main
[luser@cromer stackoverflow]$ nagfor ren.f90
NAG Fortran Compiler Release 5.3.1 pre-release(904)
Warning: ren.f90, line 17: X explicitly imported into MAIN (as LOCAL_NAME) but not used
Warning: ren.f90, line 17: Unused local variable X
[NAG Fortran Compiler normal termination, 2 warnings]
[luser@cromer stackoverflow]$ ./a.out
 foo is the new bar :)
 foo!
```

Though of course it's better to keep things private to the module if at all possible to avoid precisely this kind of thing

Comment: Yep, that is what I needed.  Good suggestion.  Coming from python I'm not used to thinking about "private" data, but python makes it *really* easy to keep namespaces separate so it's not necessary -- And there are conventions which are in place to say "Please don't mess with this variable unless you know what you're doing"

Answer (score 0):

Seems that I should have looked harder in my google search:

```
use namespace, only: namespace_x => x, namespacefoo => foo
```

"imports" namespace's `x` under the local name `namespace_x` and namespace's subroutine `foo` as `namespacefoo` in the local namespace.

Some code for the benefit of others:

```
module namespace
   real x  !some data
   real y
   contains
   subroutine foo()
     write(0,*) "foo!"
   end subroutine foo
end module

subroutine foo()
   use namespace, only: x,y
   write(0,*) "foo is the new bar :)"
   write(0,*) "by the way, namespace.x is:",x
   write(0,*) "by the way, namespace.y is:",y
end subroutine

program main
  use namespace, only: namespacefoo => foo, y, z => x
  real x
  x = 0.0
  y = 1.0
  z = 2.0
  call foo() !should print "foo is the new bar"
  call namespacefoo() !somehow call module namespace's version of foo
end program main
```

Comment: Another subtle difference with Python is that `use namespace, only: z => x` is similar to `from namespace import x as z` and will import and rename only `x`, while you can also `use namespace, z => x` to import all public entities in module `namespace` and rename only `x` (as in Ian's answer).

Comment: @sigma -- Thanks for pointing that out.  I hadn't actually read Ian's answer that carefully.